# Problem aligning items using CSS and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a basic question, but not basic for me. I am facing an issue to align div and removing some extra spacing. I have attached to screen shots. One shows how design looks right now and another shows to remove the extra space that is marked in red box and also to align right most div to the bottom and top of the left div.

Or if some one can explain what is the best way to achieve this

Any help is highly appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="mainContainer">
        <div class="topSection pd-10">
            <div class="pd-10">
                <div class="topBar">
                    <input type="text" value="36 pt">
                    <input type="text" value="Auto">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="leftAlign"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="centerAlign"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="rightAlign"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="circle"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="6" placeholder="Type logo text here"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="flexContainer">
                    <div class="iconBox mg-5">
                        <div>
                            <div class="plus"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="iconBox mg-5 ">
                        <div>
                            <div class="plus"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flexContainer">
                    <div class="iconBox mg-5">
                        <div>
                            <div class="plus"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="iconBox mg-5">
                        <div>
                            <div class="plus"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="mg-10 box">
                    <div class="logoUp"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="mg-10 box">
                    <div class="logoLeft"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="mg-10 box">
                    <div class="logoRight"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="mg-10 box">
                    <div class="logoDown"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color: #262626;
    color: #c7c7c7;
    font-family: lucidagrande;
    /* font-size: 11px; */
    font-weight: 400;
}

input[type=text] {
    background-color: #262626;
    border-color: #525252;
    color: #c7c7c7;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 10%;
    text-align: center;
}

textarea {
    background-color: #262626;
    border-color: #525252;
    color: #c7c7c7;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    /* width: 95%; */
}


/* .topSection {
    padding: 10px;
} */

.topSection>div,
.leftSection {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #323232;
}

.flexContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    margin: 10px;
}

.box {
    background-color: #262626;
    border-color: #525252;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
}

.topBar {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.topBar>div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.leftAlign {
    background: url(../images/leftAlign.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
}

.centerAlign {
    background: url(../images/centerAlign.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
}

.rightAlign {
    background: url(../images/rightAlign.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
}

.circle {
    border: solid 2px #525252;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 50px;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
}

.plus {
    background: url(../images/plus.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.iconBox {
    background-color: #262626;
    border-color: #525252;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px
}

.iconBox>div {
    background-color: #262626;
    border-color: #525252;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    border-style: dotted;
    height: 65%;
}

.logoUp {
    background: url(../images/logoUp.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
}

.logoLeft {
    background: url(../images/logoLeft.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
}

.logoRight {
    background: url(../images/logoRight.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
}

.logoDown {
    background: url(../images/logoCenter.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
}

.mg-5 {
    margin: 5px;
}

.pd-10 {
    padding: 10px;
}

.pd-5 {
    padding: 5px;
}

.pd-b-5 {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.mg-10 {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Attached required designed. I don't need a code but approach to start this design in a best way. An explanation will be helpful.

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Answer (score 1):

sorry if it's a quick solution but  it fix the problem of the space between the two elements. it's the simplest solution I didn't touch any of your elements.
i just add this properties to the pd10 class. check code :
*you can delete the margin if you want but I add it for style reasons:

```css
body {
    background-color: #262626;
    color: #c7c7c7;
    font-family: lucidagrande;
    /* font-size: 11px; */
    font-weight: 400;
}

input[type=text] {
    background-color: #262626;
    border-color: #525252;
    color: #c7c7c7;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 10%;
    text-align: center;
}

textarea {
    background-color: #262626;
    border-color: #525252;
    color: #c7c7c7;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 95%; 
 }


/* .topSection {
    padding: 10px;
} */

.topSection>div,
.leftSection {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #323232;
}

.flexContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    margin: 10px;
}

.box {
    background-color: #262626;
    border-color: #525252;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
}

.topBar {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.topBar>div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.leftAlign {
    background: url(../images/leftAlign.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
}

.centerAlign {
    background: url(../images/centerAlign.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
}

.rightAlign {
    background: url(../images/rightAlign.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
}

.circle {
    border: solid 2px #525252;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 50px;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
}

.plus {
    background: url(../images/plus.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.iconBox {
    background-color: #262626;
    border-color: #525252;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px
}

.iconBox>div {
    background-color: #262626;
    border-color: #525252;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    border-style: dotted;
    height: 65%;
}

.logoUp {
    background: url(../images/logoUp.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
}

.logoLeft {
    background: url(../images/logoLeft.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
}

.logoRight {
    background: url(../images/logoRight.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
}

.logoDown {
    background: url(../images/logoCenter.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
}

.mg-5 {
    margin: 5px;
}

.pd-10 {
    padding: 10px;
    display:flex;
    text-align-last: justify;
    margin:10px;
}

.pd-5 {
    padding: 5px;
}

.pd-b-5 {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.mg-10 {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="mainContainer">
        <div class="topSection pd-10">
            <div class="pd-10">
                <div class="topBar">
                    <input type="text" value="36 pt">
                    <input type="text" value="Auto">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="leftAlign"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="centerAlign"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="rightAlign"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="circle"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="6" placeholder="Type logo text here"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="flexContainer">
                    <div class="iconBox mg-5">
                        <div>
                            <div class="plus"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="iconBox mg-5 ">
                        <div>
                            <div class="plus"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flexContainer">
                    <div class="iconBox mg-5">
                        <div>
                            <div class="plus"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="iconBox mg-5">
                        <div>
                            <div class="plus"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="mg-10 box">
                    <div class="logoUp"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="mg-10 box">
                    <div class="logoLeft"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="mg-10 box">
                    <div class="logoRight"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="mg-10 box">
                    <div class="logoDown"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Azer8 for your help. Appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I refactored a few classes. You can check working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/1924ovfp/78/.

And here is the snippet:

```css
body {
  background-color: #262626;
  color: #c7c7c7;
  font-family: lucidagrande;
  /* font-size: 11px; */
  font-weight: 400;
}

input[type=text] {
  background-color: #262626;
  border-color: #525252;
  color: #c7c7c7;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
}

textarea {
  background-color: #262626;
  border-color: #525252;
  color: #c7c7c7;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  /* width: 95%; */
}


/* .topSection {
    padding: 10px;
} */

.flexContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  margin: 10px;
}

.box {
  background-color: #262626;
  border-color: #525252;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
}

.topBar {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.bottomBar{
 width: 100%; 
 padding-right:15px;
}

.bottomBar textarea{
   width: 98%; 
}

.topBar>div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.leftAlign {
  background: url(../images/leftAlign.png) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
}

.centerAlign {
  background: url(../images/centerAlign.png) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
}

.rightAlign {
  background: url(../images/rightAlign.png) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
}

.circle {
  border: solid 2px #525252;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
}

.plus {
  background: url(../images/plus.png) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.iconBox {
  background-color: #262626;
  border-color: #525252;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px
}

.iconBox>div {
  background-color: #262626;
  border-color: #525252;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border-style: dotted;
  height: 65%;
}

.logoUp {
  background: url(../images/logoUp.png) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
}

.logoLeft {
  background: url(../images/logoLeft.png) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
}

.logoRight {
  background: url(../images/logoRight.png) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
}

.logoDown {
  background: url(../images/logoCenter.png) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
}

.mg-5 {
  margin: 5px;
}

.pd-10 {
  padding: 10px;
}

.pd-5 {
  padding: 5px;
}

.pd-b-5 {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.mg-10 {
  margin: 10px;
}

.mainContainer {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap:5px;
}

.mainContainer>div {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #323232;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="mainContainer">
      <div class="pd-10 container_1">
        <div class="topBar">
          <input type="text" value="36 pt">
          <input type="text" value="Auto">
          <div class="box">
            <div class="leftAlign"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="box">
            <div class="centerAlign"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="box">
            <div class="rightAlign"></div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="circle"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottomBar">
          <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="6" placeholder="Type logo text here"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container_2">
        <div class="flexContainer">
          <div class="iconBox mg-5">
            <div>
              <div class="plus"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="iconBox mg-5 ">
            <div>
              <div class="plus"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flexContainer">
          <div class="iconBox mg-5">
            <div>
              <div class="plus"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="iconBox mg-5">
            <div>
              <div class="plus"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container_3">
        <div class="mg-10 box">
          <div class="logoUp"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="mg-10 box">
          <div class="logoLeft"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="mg-10 box">
          <div class="logoRight"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="mg-10 box">
          <div class="logoDown"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score -2):

In your CSS file, add width to 40%.
I think it will correct your problem.

```
.pd-10 {

    padding: 10px;
    width: 40%;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your second que.

Comment: This is a completely wrong answer.